# Copy an existing system with ansible?

Tags: ansible

Using [ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible), what is the easiest way of creating a "copy" of an existing system?

(The system in my case being LinuxMint 13)

Would I have to create a playbook by hand based on the output of `dpkg --get-selections` and various config files or is there an easier way?

(Maybe some export/backup tool that can take over the manual labour?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ansible is not really designed to "copy" an existing system.
You'll have to create a playbook by hand.

You could take a look at https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint. It's created to reverse-engineer servers. However, it does not support Mint 13, its output is Chef, Puppet or Bash, not Ansible and it has not been updated in a few months...But that project does what you are thinking of.

Comment: I ended up running Blueprint to get a list of *everyting* on the system and creating an Ansible playbook from that list.